# What are the changes in PKI when i move from TLS protocol to IPSec Protocol?

Tags: tls, public-key-infrastructure, ipsec

Currently i am using TLS protocol for a secure communication between my server and client. I use PKI for key/certificate Management. If i want to switch to IPsec for secure communication, how will the PKI be affected or what changes should i do?

Comment: That is going to depend entirely on your implementation

Comment: One of the changes is that each IPSEC peer has to have a certificate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TLS is authentication at the application level while IPSec is essentially authentication of a device. In TLS it is common that the client only authenticates the server while in IPSec both peers authenticate each other (i.e. mutual authentication). This means your PKI must now reflects devices and not applications and it needs to reflect both sides of a communication. How this affects your specific existing PKI is unknown.